# How to initialize a variable of a slot in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKaif.jpg)

And I want all rows to be displayed by default.
I am using this slot:

```
<template v-slot:item="{ item, expand, isExpanded }">
```

How can I initialize the variable **isExpanded** to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. I simulate click in the mounted() this way:

```
  mounted() {

    setTimeout(function(){
      for(let i =0; i<this.parentList.length; i++){
        let elem = this.$refs['expandButton'+this.parentList[i].ID]
        elem.click()
      }

    }, 1000 );

  },
```

In template I have this:

```
button :ref="'expandButton'+item.ID"
```